# In Eclipse, AVD stays on Android Logo

Tags: android, android-emulator

I go to my `androidmanifest.xml` and click Run > Run. AVD comes up as `5554: Testing` and it permanently stays on the Android Logo. Was there something else I was supposed to do for this to work?

Comment: Wait for a few hours. Emulators are slow. If it still doesn't go away, try creating a different emulator and trying with that

Comment: What do you mean `create a different emulator`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should open a .java file before you click Run > Run. Also, the emulator can be pretty slow to start so give it plenty of time and it will eventually show you the unlock screen.

Comment: Thank YOU! I've been wondering what the crap was going on! Thank goodness I don't have to go through the crap of transfering to my phone and running through AIDE!